# how to read in and spilt lines from one txt file and copy to a new txt file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, split

I am trying to copy one .txt file into a new file with python, but I want to separate the lines, and then split them with a tab before writing them into a new file. Here is what I have so far:

```
with open("dnaseq.txt") as data:
    lines = data.readlines()
    with open("ouput.txt", "w") as output:
        output.writelines(lines)
```

This will copy the file into the new file but I am not sure how to split up the lines, so that each line can be processed separately. I know I need to use some sort of a for loop but I do not know much past that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("dnaseq.txt") as data, open("ouput.txt", "w") as output:
    lines = data.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       #do whatever processing to line
       output.write(line)
```

data.readlines() returns a list of lines. Just iterate through the list items and write it out line by line.